# How to create a drop down, "checkbox" menu that triggers videos to appear on website?

Tags: html, button, video, checkbox

I'm a teacher and want to add a simple element to my website that lets students select, from a "checkbox" menu, which problems they missed on a practice test, and then display particular videos specific to the boxes they checked after they click "submit".

Below, I have code for a checkbox menu with a "submit" button; does anybody know how I can link my videos to particular boxes?

```
    <div>
    Test 23
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="deny" value="1" id="deny" />
    <label for="deny">Click if you want the solution to #1!</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="deny" value="1" id="deny" />
    <label for="deny">Click if you want the solution to #2!</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="deny" value="1" id="deny" />
    <label for="deny">Click if you want the solution to #3!</label>
</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" >
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried to date? Are you looking for a server side solution or a client side solution? Also your `id` attributes need to be unique and surely the values being the same is an error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response!  I'm a total novice but I think I'm looking for a server side solution-- that means the videos will be stored somewhere before my students access them, right?  And I copied and pasted the code for the three different checkboxes, and just changed the names!  Do you think I should take an "HTML 101" type course before posting questions on here?

Comment: Definatly get a bit of learing/expiericne under your belt first. You'd also by heading away from pure html here. You can have links (`a` tags) to your videos but this would not work  in a pure HTML sense with check boxes. If you go server side you'd need a language of frame work... php, asp.net, ruby on rails etc. Client side you start entering the world of javascript

Comment: This is very helpful.  In your opinion, should I start with PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: I started With javascript... so I'd go there